# Linking against two different version of library

Tags: linux, linker, elf

how is it possible that openssl is linked to the other version of libcrypto in relate to curl? Where it is defined in ELF format file?

`ldd openssl` gives me

```
libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f5d78c49000)
```

`ldd curl` gives me

```
libcrypto.so.1.0.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.2 (0x00007fd38571c000)
```

---

```
readelf --dynamic /usr/bin/curl

Dynamic section at offset 0x2fab0 contains 27 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcurl.so.4]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libz.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

There is no listed `libcrypto.so.1.1`. Why?

Comment: Why not? Or, what's your question, exactly?

Comment: Shared library resolution is recursive. Hence you'll need to apply `readelf` to the shared libraries you discovered. My educated guess would be `libcurl.4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the `NEEDED` entries in the dynamic section. The SONAME of a shared library is recorded at link time.

My results are from Fedora 29 x86_64, so on that platform both packages were built against the same shared library. Your output indicates that `openssl` is from OpenSSL 1.1.x package, but `curl` was built against OpenSSL 1.0.2.

```
$ readelf --dynamic /usr/bin/openssl | fgrep NEEDED
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libssl.so.1.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcrypto.so.1.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libz.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

```
$ readelf --dynamic /usr/bin/curl | fgrep NEEDED
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcurl.so.4]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libmetalink.so.3]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libssl.so.1.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcrypto.so.1.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libz.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```